# Using a button to call a directive that is inside of another directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have angular code that creates a div using 'box1' directive. Inside of that box there is a button. When that button is clicked I want it to call another directive that is called 'box2'. This box2 will go inside of box1. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div>
         <box1>
         </box1>
     </div>
</div>
```

ANGULAR:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("box1", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div id="group_1">Content from the first box! <button>Create 2nd Box</button></div>'
    }
});

app.directive("box2", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div id="group_1_1"> Content from second box! </div>',
    }
});
```

What is the proper way in Angular to make the button in the first box call the box2 directive. Also I can't just write  inside of box1 directive template because it will just auto generate box2. I don't want that. I want them to click inside of box1's button to make box2.

Link to JsFiddle if anyone is interested.
http://jsfiddle.net/RZSKe/

Comment: What exactly does "call the box2 directive" mean? To render the box2 directive?

Comment: Box2 directive is what I want to populate inside of box1 when a button is pressed inside of the box1 template. So yes render box2

Comment: See if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/RZSKe/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but it seems that you should make use of the `$compile` service. Here is a seed of what I mean by it - it should be probably tailored to your needs:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("box1", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div id="group_1">Content from the first box! <button ng-click="createBox2()">Create 2nd Box</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.createBox2 = function () {
                var box2 = $compile("<box2></box2>")(scope);
                el.append(box2);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive("box2", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div id="group_1_1"> Content from second box! </div>',
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**---DEMO---**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/TW387/)